# Get element location from response

Tags: javascript, html

Get location of element from html string

I've tried parsing the java script and calling the position method.

```
var html= document.createElement( 'html' );
html.innerHTML = event.data; //this is a html string return from a jquery get 
var el = html.getElementsByClassName("class")[0];
el.getBoundingClientRect(); // always 0 for top, right, bottom, left
```

I expect output to be the exact location of the element

Comment: getBoundingClientRect() never returns a number, so I don't understand "always 0".  It returns an object.

Comment: Please post the relevant html which defines the elements you're retrieving using `var el = html.getElementsByClassName("class")[0];`

Comment: thats the result of a jquery get

Comment: Well, as @jackbashford said getBoundingClientRect should work so we need a working sample of your code that clearly shows that behaviour - otherwise it's like fishing in muddy waters.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `element` is a `<html>` element. The `getBoundingClientRect` method works perfectly:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("text").getBoundingClientRect());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

```html
<p>
  <span>  
    <p id="text">Text</p>
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: sorry i had the wrong code, ive fixed it but still doesnt work. The html string wont have any css so maye thats why?

Answer (score 0):

`var el = html.getElementById("#id");` is wrong. First test if you get the element correctly `getBoundingClientRect()` will return object then just choose what you need `getBoundingClientRect().top` ... ect

Remove the hashtag
`var el = html.getElementById("id");`